# Real time count down using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need one some code for solving the problem of real time count down like deals expiry time in shopping sites.

I have a expiry time in mysql and when ever the page shown this will show the expiry time. and it will also calculate the packet delivery time after responce reached to the client with based on server time.

Comment: People are here to provide help, not to work for you. Please provide your code, the solutions you tried, what problems do you have to face...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQUERY to achieve it..

```
$(function(){
    $("#future_date").countdowntimer({
                dateAndTime : "2018/01/01 00:00:00"‚
        size : "lg"‚
        regexpMatchFormat: "([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})"‚
            regexpReplaceWith: "$1<sup>days</sup> / $2<sup>hours</sup> / $3<sup>minutes</sup> / $4<sup>seconds</sup>"
    });
});
```

Copied from: http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/